# Lego Dimension Unable To Login

Tags: wii-u, lego-dimensions

On WiiU when I 1st start the lego dimension starter set it says connecting to Lego Dimension....it hangs at this screen an finally will show press X to cancel.  I can never get the game to connect.  My wifi is connected and running fine on the WiiU but for whatever reason it is unable to connect to the Lego Dimension server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had exactly the same problem before, on the Xbox One.  It also often times out on the Xbox 360 with other recent Lego games (ie, Lego Batman 3)  I think this must be a glitch on the server side for Lego Dimensions.  No doubt many people picked up the game for Christmas and their servers are overloaded.

I've never had an issue waiting for the timeout and skipping the server connection, so I imagine the benefits of the connection must be relatively slim.